# how to control appearance of code blocks?

Tags: xetex, emacs, code, org-mode

I use Emacs org-mode and don't edit TeX directly. Is there a way for me to instruct xelatex on how to interpret my org-mode code blocks?

I'd like all my code blocks to appear as block quotes, i.e. with line wrapping, not in a fixed width font, and with left and right indents exactly like block quotes.

Comment: This is really about Org-mode, not TeX: I'm minded to migrate to SuperUser as a result.

Comment: Sure, can you do that?